# No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH after installing Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, kannel

I want to install Kannel gateway on windowsXP. For that I downloaded and installed Cygwin. But when I went to configure the Kannel I got the following errors. (I set the PATH as C:\cygwin\bin;C:\libxml2-2.6.30+.win32\bin;)

```
Running system checks ...
checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The log file is as follows.

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.62.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = sreeni9
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.7.1(0.218/5/3)
uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-5.1
uname -v = 2009-12-07 11:48

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = i686
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/libxml2-2.6.30+.win32/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin
PATH: .


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2053: checking build system type
configure:2071: result: i686-pc-cygwin
configure:2093: checking host system type
configure:2108: result: i686-pc-cygwin
configure:2180: checking for gcc
configure:2210: result: no
configure:2277: checking for cc
configure:2324: result: no
configure:2380: checking for cl.exe
configure:2410: result: no
configure:2439: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-cygwin
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-cygwin

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
CC=''
CFLAGS=''
CONVERT=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DOCDRAFTS=''
DOCSTARGET=''
DVIPS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXE_EXT=''
FIG2DEV=''
GREP=''
GW_VERSION=''
HTML_DSL=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
JADE=''
JADETEX=''
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MYSQL_CONFIG=''
OBJEXT=''
OPENSSL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PCRE_CONFIG=''
PDFJADETEX=''
PERL=''
PGSQL_CONFIG=''
PKGADD_NAME='Kannel - WAP and SMS gateway'
PKGADD_PKG='KANNELgateway'
PKGADD_VENDOR='www.kannel.org'
RANLIB=''
SDB_CONFIG=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SIZEOF_INT=''
SIZEOF_LONG=''
SIZEOF_LONG_LONG=''
SIZEOF_SHORT=''
SQLITE3=''
SQLITE=''
STARTSTOPDAEMONSRC=''
SUFFIX=''
TEX_DSL=''
VERSION='1.4.3'
XML_CONFIG=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_CC=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-cygwin'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='cygwin'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${prefix}/share/doc/kannel'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-cygwin'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='cygwin'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define GW_NAME "Kannel"
#define GW_VERSION "1.4.3"
#define VERSION "1.4.3"

configure: exit 1
```

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like you didn't install gcc when you installed cygwin. Rerun setup, selecting gcc for installation.

Comment: The correct package is gcc-g++ as indicated in Himanshu's answer. There is no gcc package in cygwin.

Answer (score 10):

Well, my first guess is that you haven't actually installed *all* of Cygwin. The default installation does not install every single package, just a subset.

That's why I always change the install type to 'Full' when I'm running `setup.exe`<sup>(a)</sup>.

Whether `gcc` is included in the standard install, I don't know, since I never install the standard one. However, it should be in `/usr/bin/gcc`, the same as my system, and which is on your path. Open up the bash shell and execute:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/gcc
```

to see if it's there.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Just keep in mind this isn't a *fast* process, potentially taking *many* hours to download/install, which is why I tend to download a new release *once* and use that cached copy to install *many* times.

Comment: http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe is the setup program. When you run this, download _everything_ to local disk and burn to a DVD, then install _everything_ from there. That way, you only ever have to download once.

Comment: @sekar.malepati you can also try using `apt-cyg` installing it like apt-get or yum on other *nix distributions

Comment: If you don't want to install everything you can run the command shown on [this website](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/). 
`setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel`

Comment: Do both Cygwin and GCC have to be in the PATH, or would it suffice for Cygwin to be on it in order for GCC to work?

Comment: Also, on Cygwin there is no `usr/bin`. The GCC packages seem to be located at `cygwin64\lib\gcc`.

Comment: @Hashim, from the bash shell, `/usr/bin` *does* exist. The path you're talking about is if you're running Windows `cmd.exe`, in which case it would be `c:\cygwin\bin\gcc`.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I'm aware of the difference between CMD and bash paths, but I was referring to the actual directory structure in Windows. When looking at it through Windows Explorer, there simply is no `usr` within `bin`, and the `gcc` packages are located at `C:\cygwin\lib\gcc`.

Comment: @Hashim, I'm not entirely clear what your contention is specifically in regard to my answer, perhaps you could clarify or suggest what you would like changed, if anything. I clearly stated "Open up the ***bash*** shell and execute ..." so, while the fact it may be in a different path when viewed from `cmd`/Explorer is interesting, I'm not sure I see the relevance.

Comment: Maybe a warning should be displayed on this post. I don't know if this comes from me following this solution 10 years after (!), but I spent the whole day trying to install the full Cygwin ; currently, I'm 80% complete with 11 hours spent (yet) and 17Go of packages downloaded... This should not be attempted lightly !

Comment: @tgrandje, you're correct, it has never been a fast process, warning added :-)

Answer (score 4):

This mean you have cygwin which does not contain the gcc-g++ compiler.

run setup(setup-x86_64.exe) again and now select package

> gcc-g++

and then the setup will work fine.
I tested that and worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the `apt-cyg`, you can use bellow command for install it:

```
apt-cyg install gcc-g++
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select gcc, gdb , make etc while installing cygwin , those options are not default . can be found in devel tab of packages.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you choose one of the offered options other than "Install from Internet" in the Cygwin Setup dialog:

[image]

If you use the other options, it seems you can end up with missing files. I tried on two different machines and in both cases there was only a single file in the Devel category, nothing to do with gcc. This despite going through line by line and checking everything for a full install.

In desperation I was trying anything I could think of, and as soon as I tried "Install from Internet", both machines immediately showed a huge list in the Devel category including the gcc entries, and I then got a full install.

It may have been a mirror/download glitch, as I found that after using the internet option, I could not then reproduce the original problem on either machine. (I tried to do so, to get a screenshot for this post.) But it would seem odd to get the same download glitch twice in a row on different machines.

Regardless of exactly how it can happen, the fact remains, the download appeared successful and at no time was I notified of any problem, so there was no indication of any reason to doubt that I had downloaded the full set of files. And the net effect was, after making the choice to download to disk and then install from that, I was forever stuck with missing files, with no clue as to what the problem was. By a lucky chance I stumbled on the fact that using the internet option would fix the problem.

Comment: Downvoters please comment! This helped me and at least one upvoter. If it can be improved or corrected in some way, don't stay silent.